# Can several domain users svn update a network folder on a Windows Domain

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windowsdomainaccount

We have a network folder on the Windows domain in which we would like to keep the release source codes. We would like to be able to build the code on the machine of a random developer of our team.

So I created a network folder and checked out the source code into it. Whenever I do an Update, there aren't any problems. But it looks like no one else but me is able to do an update into that folder. They get the following error in tortoisesvn:

```
Working copy "blabla" locked
sqlite: attempt to write a readonly database
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the hidden files (.svn directories)?

Answer (score 3):

Working Copy on network drive (and repository also) was and is always Bad Idea (tm)

Quote [from Simon Large](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2709351&orderBy=createDate&orderType=desc)

> Placing repositories on a network share has always been discouraged
>   very strongly. Sharing working copies has always been strongly
>   discouraged too, because it negates the whole point if having revision
>   control.

Additional reading:

- [Permission problems with working copies on a SAMBA share](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#samba)
- [Having working folder located on network drive](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tortoisesvn/6OQToZ8OabQ)
- [Working folder on a network share](http://www.svnforum.org/archive/index.php/t-40133.html?s=a533b038e7c3c7fe3b55ca7ee06a6955)

Comment: Ok, but we are all developing in our source code. Where should we keep the release version of the code? For example: I urgently need to fix a bug, but I'm working on something else. In that case, I would fix the bug, check in the code and recompile the release version. I don't want to compile my code, as it contains other modifications that I don't want to compile.

Comment: @Liezzzje - please, read SVN Book, fist chapter, in order to be able to speak on common language. Anyway "release version" you'll store on *some URL* **in Repository**, you asked about dealing **with Working Copy**. Read about branches in Subversion and in SCM in common